# Having trouble getting a handle to a Dockable Pane C++

Tags: c++, mfc

I created a multi doc ribbon based MFC application through the MFC Wizard. Im trying to get a handle to m_wndFileView to update its view. I know there are several ways to do it but Im not understanding why the method Im using is not working. Soooo to start

```
class CMainFrame : public CMDIFrameWndEx
{
    ...
    CFileView         m_wndFileView;
    CPropertiesWnd    m_wndProperties;
    ...
}

class CFileView : public CDockablePane
{
    ...
    protected:
        CViewTree m_wndFileView;
    ...
};

class CPropertiesWnd : public CDockablePane
{
    ...
    protected:
        CMFCPropertyGridCtrl m_wndPropList;
    ...
};
```

The main frame is created from MAINAPPLICATION.cpp

```
// create main MDI Frame window
CMainFrame* pMainFrame = new CMainFrame;
if (!pMainFrame || !pMainFrame->LoadFrame(IDR_MAINFRAME))
{
    delete pMainFrame;
    return FALSE;
}
m_pMainWnd = pMainFrame;

// call DragAcceptFiles only if there's a suffix
//  In an MDI app, this should occur immediately after setting m_pMainWnd
// Enable drag/drop open
m_pMainWnd->DragAcceptFiles();

// Parse command line for standard shell commands, DDE, file open
CCommandLineInfo cmdInfo;
ParseCommandLine(cmdInfo);

// Enable DDE Execute open
EnableShellOpen();
RegisterShellFileTypes(TRUE);


// Dispatch commands specified on the command line.  Will return FALSE if
// app was launched with /RegServer, /Register, /Unregserver or /Unregister.
if (!ProcessShellCommand(cmdInfo))
    return FALSE;
// The main window has been initialized, so show and update it
pMainFrame->ShowWindow(m_nCmdShow);
pMainFrame->UpdateWindow();
```

MainFrm.cpp creates these two panes:

```
// Create file view
CString strFileView;
bNameValid = strFileView.LoadString(IDS_FILE_VIEW);
ASSERT(bNameValid);
if (!m_wndFileView.Create(strFileView, this, CRect(0, 0, 200, 200), TRUE, ID_VIEW_FILEVIEW, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | CBRS_LEFT| CBRS_FLOAT_MULTI))
{
    TRACE0("Failed to create File View window\n");
    return FALSE; // failed to create
}


// Create properties window
CString strPropertiesWnd;
bNameValid = strPropertiesWnd.LoadString(IDS_PROPERTIES_WND);
ASSERT(bNameValid);
if (!m_wndProperties.Create(strPropertiesWnd, this, CRect(0, 0, 200, 200), TRUE, ID_VIEW_PROPERTIESWND, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | CBRS_RIGHT | CBRS_FLOAT_MULTI))
{
    TRACE0("Failed to create Properties window\n");
    return FALSE; // failed to create
}
```

From MAINAPPLICATION.cpp, I can access the properties pane through

```
CWnd * pwnd = ((CWnd*)(AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd));
CPropertiesWnd * pPropertiesWnd = (CPropertiesWnd*)pwnd->GetDlgItem(ID_VIEW_PROPERTIESWND);
CMFCPropertyGridCtrl * m_wndPropList = (CMFCPropertyGridCtrl *)pPropertiesWnd->GetDlgItem(2);
```

but for some reason I cannot access the fileview pane with

```
CWnd * pwnd = ((CWnd*)(AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd));
CFileView * pFileViewWnd = (CFileView*)pwnd->GetDlgItem(ID_VIEW_FILEVIEW);
CViewTree * m_wndFileView= (CViewTree*)pFileViewWnd ->GetDlgItem(4);
```

the (CFileView*)pwnd->GetDlgItem(ID_VIEW_FILEVIEW); returns NULL

please help. This is driving me crazy. In the end I can modify the m_wndPropList but not the m_wndFileView because I cannot get a handle to pFileViewWnd. Two  panes created in the same way cannot be accessed in the same way. Why? If more code is needed, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Use `Spy++` to verify that the fileview pane has the proper ID and is a child of the main window.

Comment: @MarkRansom  well that answered a lot. Thanks for the help. Apparently i was doing everything right but according to msdn and spy++ when the two dockable panes are attached via AttachToTabWnd() another window is created so that the two dockable panes can exist in it as tabs(the file view had a class view attached to it while the properties view had no attachments). In order for me to get access i need to find out how to get a hold of this dynamically created tabbed window. An adventure for tomorrow. Thanks for your help. I tried to give you a point but the darn thing wouldnt let me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a inline getters in `CMainFrame` class like this:

```
CFileView& GetFileViewPane()
{
  return m_wndFileView;
}

CPropertiesWnd& GetPropsPane()
{
  return m_wndProperties;
}
```

After that you can access those windows just like this:

```
CMainFrame* pMainFrame = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CMainFrame, AfxGetMainWnd());
if (pMainFrame && pMainFrame->GetSafeHwnd()) // sanity check
{
  pMainFrame->GetFileViewPane().DoStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So @MarkRansom really helped out with the spy++ idea. To get a handle, I had to do the following:

```
// get CWnd to main window
CWnd * pwnd = ((CWnd*)(AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd));
// from spy++ i found that the tabbed panes were in a window called
// "File View" so i found a child window with that title
HWND h = FindWindowExW(pwnd->GetSafeHwnd(), NULL, NULL, L"File View");
// casted it to a tabbedpane pointer
CTabbedPane * pFileViewWn = (CTabbedPane *)CWnd::FromHandle(h);
// mfc wizard did what seems to me as weird naming. to find the docking 
// panes i did the same as above but there was no title to this window
HWND hh = FindWindowExW(pFileViewWn->GetSafeHwnd(), NULL, NULL, L"");
// casted that
CDockablePane* pTabbedBar = (CDockablePane*)CWnd::FromHandle(hh);
// was able to find my specific docking pane using a resource id
CFileView * pFileViewWnd = (CFileView*)pTabbedBar->GetDlgItem(ID_VIEW_FILEVIEW);
// was able to find the control i wanted to use using a resource id
CViewTree * m_wndFileView = (CViewTree *)pFileViewWnd->GetDlgItem(4);

HTREEITEM hRoot = m_wndFileView->GetRootItem();

m_wndFileView->InsertItem(name, 2, 2, hRoot);
```

Going through the code i would think that the logic would be

```
tabbed pane
    File View Dockable Pane
        File View controls
    Class View Dockable Pane
        Class View controls
```

but somehow another window slide its way in to make

```
tabbed pane
    MYSTERY DOCKABLE WINDOW
        File View Dockable Pane
            File View controls
        Class View Dockable Pane
            Class View controls
```

Comment: Totally horrible way of doing it.

Comment: @ Andrew Komiagin 
Yea :-/ 
was just trying to understand the make-up of mfc using its wizard. This little problem stumped me